# How can i solve this error getting during running solochain?

Tags: solo-chain

```
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_benchmarking_current_time_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_wipe_db_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_get_read_and_written_keys_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_reset_read_write_count_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_commit_db_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_read_write_count_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_set_whitelist_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_add_to_whitelist_version_1', 'env:ext_benchmarking_proof_size_version_1'")))
```

I am just running the solochain with the command

```
./target/release/main-node key insert --base-path  /tmp/node01 \
--chain ./res/TestnetSpecRaw.json \
--scheme Sr25519 \
--suri <third_keyset-aura-secret-seed> \
--key-type aura
```

```
./target/release/main-node key insert --base-path  /tmp/node01 \
--chain ./res/TestnetSpecRaw.json \
--scheme Ed25519 \
--suri <third_keyset-granpa-secret-seed> \
--key-type gran
```

```
./target/release/main-node \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain ./res/TestnetSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9945 \
  --rpc-port 9933 \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode01
```

Comment: Check this: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/cannot-run-benchmarking-did-not-find-the-benchmarking-metadata

Comment: we already have this code in our chain

impl sc_executor::NativeExecutionDispatch for ExecutorDispatch {
 /// Only enable the benchmarking host functions when we actually want to benchmark.
 #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
 type ExtendHostFunctions = frame_benchmarking::benchmarking::HostFunctions;
 /// Otherwise we only use the default Substrate host functions.
 #[cfg(not(feature = "runtime-benchmarks"))]
 type ExtendHostFunctions = ();
}

Comment: What did you modify about the code of the node? Can you provide a link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create the spec on the other system. That was because of the Rust version installed in the system by which we created the specs.